# Scrapy - How do i return data to main parse method from yielded request?

Tags: python, scrapy, yield

So i've been stuck on this for a couple of days. 
I'm parsing through a JSON object that contains some info.
In this object there's a list containing n number of contacts. Each of those has an id that can be used to create a url. In that url there's the phonenumber for that contact.

So i want to start creating an item, add some info, then loop through the contacts, and for each loop i want to add to that original item with the phonenumber found in the url.

My problem:
How do i return the scraped phonenumber and add it to the item?
If i end the main parse method with "yield items", none of the data scraped in the loop gets added to the item. But if i instead end the parseContact with "yield items" the entire item gets duplicated for each loop.

Please help, i'm about to have a meltdown :D

Here's the code:

```
def parse(self, response):

        items = projectItem()
        rData = response.xpath('//*[@id="data"]/text()').get()
        dData = json.loads(rData)
        listOfContacts = dData["contacts"]
        Data = dData["customer"]

        items['customername'] = Data["companyName"]
        items['vatnumber'] = Data["vatNo"]
        items['contacts'] = []


        i=0
        for p in listOfContacts:
            id = json.dumps(p["key"])
            pid = id.replace("\"","")
            urlP = urljoin("https://example.com/?contactid=", pid)
            items['contacts'].append({"pid":pid,"name":p["name"]})

            yield scrapy.Request(urlP, callback=self.parseContact,dont_filter=True,cb_kwargs={'items':items},meta={"counter":i})
            i +=1
        #IF I YIELD HERE, NONE OF THE DATA IN THE LOOP GETS SAVED    
        yield items 




    def parseContact(self, response,items):
        i = response.meta['counter']

        data = response.xpath('//*[@id="contactData"]/script/text()').get()
        items['contacts'][i].update({"data":data})
        #IF I YIELD HERE THE ITEM iS DUPLICATED N TIMES
        yield items
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want 1 item per company, you need to build up the item completely before yielding it.
I would do it like this:

```
import json
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urljoin

def parse(self, response):
    items = projectItem()
    rData = response.xpath('//*[@id="data"]/text()').get()
    dData = json.loads(rData)
    listOfContacts = dData["contacts"]
    Data = dData["customer"]
    items['contacts'] = []

    items['customername'] = Data["companyName"]
    items['vatnumber'] = Data["vatNo"]
    contacts_info = []
    # prepare list with the contact urls, pid & name
    for p in listOfContacts:
        id = json.dumps(p["key"])
        pid = id.replace("\"", "")
        urlP = urljoin("https://example.com/?contactid=", pid)
        contacts_info.append((urlP, pid, p["name"]))
    # get the first item from the list, and pass the rest of the list along in the meta
    urlP, pid, name = contacts_info.pop()
    yield scrapy.Request(urlP,
                         callback=self.parseContact,
                         dont_filter=True,
                         meta={"contacts_info": contacts_info,
                               "items": items})

def parseContact(self, response, items):
    contacts_info = response.meta['contacts_info']
    # get count from meta, or default to 0
    count = response.meta.count('count', 0)
    count += 1
    items = response.meta['items']
    data = response.xpath('//*[@id="contactData"]/script/text()').get()
    items['contacts'][count].update({"data": data})
    try:
        urlP, pid, name = contacts_info.pop()
    except IndexError:
        # list contacts info is empty, so the item is finished and can be yielded
        yield items
    else:
        yield scrapy.Request(urlP,
                             callback=self.parseContact,
                             dont_filter=True,
                             meta={"contacts_info": contacts_info,
                                   "items": items,
                                   "count": count})
```

I'm not sure what the link is between pid & counter (so the part about adding the pid & name needs to be added in the code), but I hope you get the idea here.

Comment: Thank you!I had to re-write some stuff, but your solution is exactly what i needed.